# I can't divide 2 count(*) values without returning zero

Tags: db2, count, cast

The statement I'm using is for a KPI in Maximo and I currently have this statement:

```
select (select count(*) from incident where incident.slanum = 'USERADMIN' and 
 incident.actualfinish > incident.targetresolve and date(incident.actualfinish) >= 
 current_date-(day(current_date)-1)days) / (select count(*) from incident where 
 incident.slanum = 'USERADMIN' and date(incident.actualfinish) >= current_date-
 (day(current_date)-1)days) from dummy_table
```

This returns a zero, because I'm dividing 2 integers I have realised. But I cannot work out what the syntax needs to be to use CAST or CONVERT to be able to successfully divide one figure by the other.

Please help!

Thanks, Will

Comment: How about `CAST(firstcount AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / CAST(secondcount AS DECIMAL(10,2))`?

Comment: Thanks @RLF, I tried it, but Maximo still doesn't like it, returns an unexpected error, which is generally the message it gives if the syntax is wrong. Here's what I tried: select (select cast (count(*) from incident where incident.slanum = 'USERADMIN' and incident.actualfinish > incident.targetresolve and date(incident.actualfinish) >= current_date-(day(current_date)-1)days AS DECIMAL(10,2))) / (select cast (count(*) from incident where incident.slanum = 'USERADMIN' and date(incident.actualfinish) >= current_date-(day(current_date)-1)days as decimal(10,2))) from dummy_table

Comment: Thanks for the edit @davisdba - unfortunately I can't work out how to edit my reply above to also be in the same formatting :-)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm not too knowledgeable on all that @a_horse_with_no_name , but I'm putting the query directly into the Maximo KPI manager front end. The data base in the background is DB2. Hope that is what you meant?

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name, you need to cast `INTEGER` `COUNT()`s -- but you seem to attempt casting the entire select statements instead. That should look more like `select cast( count(*) as decimal(10,2)) from incident where ...`